Weak and strong integrability of a mapping $f : X \to E$ on a general measure space $X$ and locally convex $E$
Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and $E$ be a locally convex toplogical vector space.
Let us consider a mapping $f : X \to E$. Then, we have two notions of integrability. That is, weak integrability as well as strong or Bochner integrability.
Now, my question is:

If $E$ is separable, is $f$ weakly integrable iff strongly integrable?

In the original paper by Pettis, he only considers $X$ to be some interval, so I am not sure if it can generalize to arbitrary measure spaces... and it is quite tantalizing that I have not been able to find a reference explicitly answering the above question....
Could anyone please help?

Ref.: Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl

@geetha290krm Oh..thank you. My search has not been enough, obviously..
